# are continous insert and delete operations on a single database table a valid design?

Tags: database

i have an application, where in for every request on reaching the application server, all its attributes are stored in a particular table with a unique request Id. And on completion of the processing of the request(i.e., on generation of the response but before sending the response to the client), based on the unique request id, the corresponding row is deleted from the table. Now, an application on an average can process a very large of number of requests. So this means a huge amount of insert operations and then corresponding delete operations on a single table.Will it affect the database performance and its stability ?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO yes to "valid design" or to "affect performance and stability"?

Comment: *affect performance and stability* ... You may want to figure out a way to not delete the rows immediately due to the cost associated with this action.

Comment: To me, this design sounds like a bad substitute for a properly designed model using known design patterns and separation of concerns.

Comment: Does this really need to be stored in a database, and not just kept within the application?

Comment: Couldn't you store that request data in the session data? or otherwise if using mysql as your data is temporary you could use a memory table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html which is very fast performance wise as it its stored in memory not in hard disk.

Comment: Depending on the DBMS, this design (or rather, this usage pattern) may require frequent freespace management (e.g., VACUUM on postgresql), which can cause quite some I/O.